# CSS design mods and issue with old IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

The top navigation at http://ci2.totalshopuk.com has dividers on the left which means the last link doesn't have a divider. I would either like to remove the first divider or add one at the end.

I copied the .navmenuitem1 style and made a new one .navmenuitemfirst1 and removed the background but strangely the first link was put on a line above the rest!? (even a straight copy of the style does the same thing).

Example:-

```
<ul class="navmenu1">
    <li class="navmenuitemfirst1"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navmenuitem1"><a href="/download">Download</a></li>
    <li class="navmenuitem1"><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="navmenuitem1"><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="navmenuitem1"><a href="/newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
    <li class="navmenuitem1"><a href="/license">License</a></li>
    <li class="navmenuitem1"><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Lastly, in IE6 none of the background images show, I just get the colour as the background... however the backgrounds on the original table design at http://www.totalshopuk.com show correctly.

Any help is very much appreciated!

-- Duplicating all .navmenuitem styles fixed the divider issue --

```
.navmenuitemfirst,.navmenuitem {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navmenuitemfirst a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.navmenuitem a {
    background: url(../images/navdivider.png) no-repeat;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.navmenuitemfirst a:hover,.navmenuitem a:hover {
    color: #E64D29;
}
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle so I can see the styles?

Comment: jsfiddle now created here - http://jsfiddle.net/ibizara/9DTTd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer to your first question can have to do with the a:

http://jsfiddle.net/9DTTd/1/

I created a new class for .navmenuitemfirst1 a

You might have been applying just the new class, when the background style is in the a (the a is a block with a background). I can't see any error with lines, but check it and let me know. This might also answer the second concern about the background, but I don't have ie6 to check it :3

EDIT: I later noticed why it wasn't working, silly me. The class needed to have also the inline property:

```
.navmenuitem1,.navmenuitem2,.navmenuitemfirst1 {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried initially but the Home link was put above the rest. By duplicating ".navmenuitem" as well as ".navmenuitem a" seems to have fixed the problem, not the best but If anyone else has any other solutions?!

Answer (score 0):

Probaly the .navmenuitem1 has an position:relative and float:left and the .navmenuitemfirst1 hasn't. As utopicam asked make an jsfiddle for it so we could check the css with it.